# How to select all textframes in document, and retrieve the text in adobe indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I have multiple textframes in my document and i have created a script to replace specific words from a textframe as such:

```
var linebreak = "<br/>";

     if (string.indexOf(linebreak) >= 0) {
        var string2 = string.replaceAll(linebreak, "\r");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }

myFrame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.itemByName("test");
myFrame.contents = string2;
```

But without having to choose the name of the textframe i would like to do it to all active textframes in the document

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" **inside your question**. Answers go in the box labelled "Your Answer". You are even allowed to mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but something along these lines should work:

```
var linebreak = "<br/>";

var myFrames = app.activeDocument.textFrames;

for (var i=0; i<myFrames.length; i++) {
   var myFrame = myFrames[i];
   var string = myFrame.contents;

   if (string.indexOf(linebreak) >= 0) {
      myFrame.contents = string.replaceAll(linebreak, "\r");
   } else {
      alert("false");
   }
}
```

Comment: returns an error saying "string.replaceall is not a function"

Comment: You should be able to modify it to suit your needs

Comment: @lanes123: there is no `replaceall` in Josh' code so you must have copied something wrong. Weirdly, there is no built-in `replaceAll` function either, but you seem to have it working in your own code.

Comment: @usr2564301 there is a replaceAll in the IF statement where it is getting the error. Yeah it seems to work on my one but not Josh's. Weird, any solutions?

Comment: @lanes123: JavaScript is a case sensitive language, and your first comment said it was `replaceall`, that's why I mentioned it. If it works with your own script, check *why*. Does it include more lines than you are showing here? Also, does it actually *need* a specific function, rather than a plain `replace`?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, also untested, but also should work:

```
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;

app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "<br/>";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "\\r"
activeDocument.changeGrep();
```

Answer (score 0):

*answer from OP*

**Solved:**

```
var linebreak = "<br />";
var myFrames = app.activeDocument.textFrames;

for (var i = 0; i<myFrames.length; i++) {
   var myFrame = myFrames[i];
   var string = myFrame.contents;

    if (string.indexOf(linebreak) >= 0) {
            var string2 = string.replace(new RegExp(linebreak, 'g'), '\r');
    } else {
            alert("ERROR: Cant find linebreak");
    }
   myFrame.contents = string2;
}
```